# How to see the actual memory and its properties (slot position, size, speed...)

Tags: 12.04, memory

I have 2 PCs. A Laptop dv600 and an Intel dp35dp. I want a command that shows me how many slots of memory I am using, the size, speed, etc.. For the moment the size of each would be good. Maybe see if there are slot free to use.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. System monitor will show you how much memory you have and how much you're using/is available, but that's it. . .

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
lshw -short -C memory
```

or

```
dmidecode
```

Comment: Thank you. After testing with dmidecore the exact answer for me was: `sudo dmidecode -t memory` Many thanks jet.

Comment: My system told me to run the command as super user. Add 'sudo' to the start of the command.

Answer (score 14):

I find the following more more Human friendly and it gives the Speed, Size, Slot, Dimm Type, etc...

`sudo dmidecode -t memory`

If you only need to know the actual maximum memory and amount of slots in your motherboard then do the following:

`sudo dmidecode -t 16`

Changing 16 for 17 will give you an more detail look at each memory slot in your motherboard.

Answer (score 5):

`sudo lshw -class memory` worked for me.

Under

`*-memory`

You should see

```
 *-bank:0
```

and

```
 *-bank:1
```

If you have 2 slots.  Only `*-bank` for 1 slot.